# Azure PowerShell Webjob Not Deleting Files

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a simple powershell script that I've deployed as a webjob to azure. I want it to delete files older than a time period from a top-level folder "images" (at the same level as the web "site" and Logfiles folders).

Here is the script (xxx is where the name of the site will go):

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)
$path = "C:\DWASFiles\Sites\xxx\images"
# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } 
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

And here is the output:

> [07/30/2014 20:28:45 > 4e7488: SYS INFO] Status changed to
>   Initializing [07/30/2014 20:28:45 > 4e7488: SYS INFO] Run script
>   'deleteold.ps1' with script host - 'PowerShellScriptHost' [07/30/2014
>   20:28:45 > 4e7488: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running [07/30/2014
>   20:28:46 > 4e7488: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success

Yet it's not deleting files. It works on my local system.
Have I got the wrong path here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems the correct path should be `d:\home\images`.

But to know for sure go to: `https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/` there you can see where the files are located and you can even run your script on your site to make sure it works.